# Reason For IndexError?

Tags: python, list

I have a list `tmp=['Name','Date','   ','-','MO.A2.v05.005',.... ]`. I am trying to remove the non alpha numeric entries like 'Name','Date',' ','-' and retain the 'MO.A2.v05.005' parts. I wrote the code below for this :

```
for i in range(0,len(tmp)):
...     ch=tmp[i].translate(None,'.')
...     if ~ch.isalnum():
...             tmp.remove(tmp[i])
```

I get the error as

```
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I did however get the job done with the following:

```
for i in tmp:
...     ch=i.translate(None,'')
...     if ~ch.isalnum():
...             tmp.remove(i)
...
```

Any one has any idea about why the first code didn't work

Comment: `~ch.isalnum()` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: If the list element is not alpha numeric then it is deleted. Example if `A='dfad'`, then `A.isalnum()=Fasle` and `~A.isalnum()=True`

Answer (score 3):

**Why it doesn't workd?**

**Short version** :  Because the `len(temp)` is reducing and `range()` doesn't knows it.

**Long version** The `range(0,len(tmp))` is executed only once, at the start of the for loop. This will return the list from `[0....len(temp)]` That is the current length before the start of the `for` loop.

Now the `for` loop will continue iterating over this list without knowing that the list is getting reduced to `[0....len(temp) - n ]`is subsequent iterations of the for loop

That is if initial length was 5 and we removed 2 elements from the list, then both `temp[3]` and `temp[4]` will lead to `IndexErrors` as the new list doesn't have them

**Solutions**

You can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)  instead

```
[ x for x in tmp if "." in x ]
```

**Test**

```
>>> tmp=['Name','Date','   ','-','MO.A2.v05.005']
>>> [ x for x in tmp if "." in x ]
['MO.A2.v05.005']
```